# Predictive text for global search results - only returns a few results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-results, enterprise-search, 2019

SharePoint 2019 - on premise.

My global search (classic) uses a series of verticals.

Query suggestions are turned on - I have limited knowledge of the query suggestions. I was hoping it did draw the suggestions from the metadata columns such as the name of a document or page, persons name, document description etc.

Currently I can only gather about predictive text results when I search - which is an issue.

Very happy if someone could offer some guidance as to where to begin and what I need to do to begin troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search system automatically creates suggestions for a query when users have clicked one or more of the results for that query **at least six times**.

In addition, we can manually add phrases that you want the search system to always suggest to users:

[image]

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-query-suggestions

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/query-suggestions-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Is there a way to creates suggestions for a query when users has clicked on the results for that query less than six times?

Comment: This is by design and we cannot change it.

Comment: Thanks Julie_MSFT

Comment: Just a final query - once I input the file for the query suggestions, can I update this file or add another file to the query suggestions. If so, do I need to delete the old file before adding the new?